# Is it possible to do a complete image backup of an Android device via USB connected to a Windows PC without the Android device being rooted?

Tags: usb, backup

I recently purchased a Nexus 7 tablet from Google and I also have a Samsung Skyrocket from AT&T. Neither of the devices is rooted. I'm not too enthusiastic yet about rooting either of them, especially since it voids warranties and severely limits support options. Is there a way to obtain a complete image backup of either (or both) of these devices via the USB port on my Windows computer? If so, how? Thank you!

Comment: If you're on ICS or JB, `adb backup` might be the way to do this!

Comment: @t0mm13b that will not be an issue, cuz Nexus 7 is JellyBean originally.

Answer (score 2):

Most articles I have encountered where people wish to undertake a complete image backup of their device requires root. However I have come across an article written in **How-To Geek** entitled *"How To Create a Full Android Phone or Tablet Backup Without Rooting or Unlocking Your Device"*.

The Article will take you throught the steps of :

- Installing the Android SDK
- Device Setup
- Testing ADB
- Backing up your device
- Restoring a Backup

http://www.howtogeek.com/125375/how-to-create-a-full-android-phone-or-tablet-backup-without-rooting-or-unlocking-your-device/

The article concludes by saying the complexity of using the Android SDK to create and restore backups is a bit much for the average user.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:  [[GUIDE] Full Phone Backup without Unlock or Root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1420351)

Although it is talking about Galaxy Nexus, but this method is completely compatible with your Nexus 7.