# How to do a clone / backup & restore between identical devices via USB and broken screen

Tags: backup, nexus-4, broken-screen

I have a Nexus 4 with a recently broken screen, and another Nexus 4 that works. I would like to copy all of the data, apps, etc, from the broken Nexus 4 to the working Nexus 4.  The broken phone still powers on and I can access it via USB cable, I just can't use the screen.

Is there any way to do this entirely via the USB cable, adb, etc? The methods I've seen for copying data all require installing and controlling software (such as Titanium backup, or other third-party cloning software) on the source phone. I can't very well do that, since that phone isn't fully functional.

[This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/30380/13613) is almost exactly what I want, except for the part where I must authorize the backup on my source device, which is not possible without a functioning screen.

Comment: Hi! Can you see something on the device or is it all done for? If yes, then you can authorize ADB backup or even take the backup on the device itself. OTG cable with Mouse or [input keyevents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events) would help.

Comment: I can see the display. I can reboot the device (using the buttons on the side). I just can't interact with the screen. I can even issue the 'unlock screen' key event, but as the screen is locked with a pattern, that isn't sufficient to actually unlock the screen.

Comment: That's why I gave you the hint. When you're supposed to authorize the backup use input keyevents to authorize the event (it allows to emulate directional and enter keys' functionality). Alternatively, use ADB in wireless mode and OTG cable with standard mouse to control the screen. My device's digitizer doesn't work but I'm using it for last 5 months using OTG mouse and keyevents. // For pattern, mouse would work for sure.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to authorize the backup with the key events.

Comment: Is the device rooted or a custom recovery installed? Do you have an OTG cable?

Comment: I just have a standard USB cable. I don't think I ever rooted this device. If there's a way to check, I'm happy to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29485/discussion-between-firelord-and-flimzy).

Comment: HINTS: Please take a look at our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), which helds a.o. links to related questions: [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575) / [How to backup broken screen phone when USB debugging IS NOT enabled?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/67352/16575) / [How to perform a full system dump/backup with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/54272/16575) and more.